# Problem in reading XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Hello Guys can you help me solving my problem in reading xml.
I'm just new in xml. Here's the sample xml.

```
<Org>
    <Org ID="1">
        <OrgNum>1</OrgNum>
        <OrgName>sample1</OrgName>
    </Org>
    <Org ID="2">
        <OrgNum>2</OrgNum>
        <OrgName>sample2</OrgName>
    </Org>
</Org>
```

I want to get only the *`OrgName`* with an *`Org ID = 2`*.
Here's my sample code but it's read all the text.
Help me plz..Tnx

```
string xml = Application.StartupPath + "\\OrgName.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
if (System.IO.File.Exists(xml))
{
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(xml);
    textReader.Read();
    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;
        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textReader.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using the `XmlReader` API instead of the *much* simpler DOM APIs (whether the "old-style" XmlDocument, or LINQ to XML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it with linq:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\OrgName.xml");
 var result = doc.Root.Elements("Org").Where(x=>x.Attribute("id").ToString()=="2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your life gets a lot easier if you start using tools like [xdocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), [xmldocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and [xpath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/nl)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the classic .net Xml object model, you could try this:

```
    string xml = Application.StartupPath + "\\OrgName.xml";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(xml))
    {
       xmlDoc.Load(xml);
       XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
       string orgName = root.SelectSingleNode(@"descendant::Org[@ID='1']/OrgName").InnerText;
       MessageBox.Show(orgName);
    }
```

Comment: 'descendant::Org[@ID='1']\OrgName' has an invalid token. - That's the error of your code..